# A PhD program is asking how long I need to make a decision

Tags: graduate-admissions

So, I got an unusual (to my understanding) question from a program today asking how much time will I need to accept or reject an admission offer. It's the only school that has contacted me so far and I am completely unsure how to answer that.

Does anyone have any suggestions what to do in that situation? I mean, it all seriously depends on circumstances, right?

Comment: Is this program your first choice?  If not, and you've applied to other programs, do you know (or can you find out) when they'll have made offers?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Not the first choice, but I'm still interested. It's the only program to contact me so far, I'm kind of in the dark. I don't have any info from other programs. I can send an email asking about my application's status to other schools but I'm a bit worried that it might end up hurting me.

Comment: A simple, "When do you expect to make admissions decisions" query shouldn't hurt your chances at other schools.  In some cases, this information may be available on the website of the department that you're applying to.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thank you, I guess if I phrase it this way, it should be okay. But if I respond saying "It won't take more than two weeks to make a decision", would it be a long time? Or it solely depends on the school?

Comment: Ask for what you need.  If that's too long, they'll come back with a shorter time limit and you'll have to decide whether or not you're interested.  In my experience, having offers open for at least a couple of weeks is standard.

Comment: In what country is the school located, and when did they first notify you about acceptance?

Comment: If you happen to be in the US, see my recent answer here to a questioner who made a decision too early: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/103095/pursuing-other-phd-offers-after-accepting-one-too-early/103098#103098